# How to read from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus queue populated from CRM 2016

Tags: .net-core, dynamics-crm, azure-servicebus-queues

I am looking to create a `.NET Core 2.2` console app that reads from a `Azure Service Bus Queue`. Messages are put on the queue by a `CRM 2016` instance. The plan is to use the queue to notify externals when entities are created and/or updated.

I am able to read from the queue without issue using the following sample code.

```
var queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);
...
var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(this.ExceptionReceivedHandler) {
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
    AutoComplete = false
};

queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(this.ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
...

protected async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token) {
    // do something ??? with message body
    byte[] body = message.Body;

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

I have no problems reading from the queue and getting the message **but I am unsure what to do next**. All of the examples documentation I have found seems to work with an older version of the Azure Bus library and `.NET Framework`.

Once I have the `Body` property, what do I do with it? I assume I need to deserialize or cast it as a class but what class?

The samples on this site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-one-way-listener) deal with the older library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/). The samples include references to `RemoteExecutionContext`, `BrokeredMessage` (along with a `GetBody()` method) which does not seem to apply to newer library.

The samples on this site (https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples) are about Azure Bus in general and do not deal with `CRM`.

Am I using the correct library? Should I not be using Core? Can anybody point me to sample code that runs in `.NET Core` and interacts with queues and CRM?

Comment: So, you can consume messages from the queue, but you dont know how to write to the queue - is that right?

Comment: Negative. We are writing to the queue. I can read messages off the queue. But I am unsure how to handle the Body property of the Message object when I read from the queue using .NET **Core** and the new `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` library. The classes that are in all of the documentation and samples for the **older library do not exist in the new**. And I cannot find any .NET Core sample apps.

Answer (score 0):

The old ServiceBus SDK seems to do some deserialization for you, this you will need to do yourself now.

Looking at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-persistent-queue-listener) it seems that there is a Dynamics class called `RemoteExecutionContext` that is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327767(v%3Dcrm.8)) and [reading this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/224938) it suggests you can set the data to be sent as JSON, looks like the default might be XML, but I've no idea.

If the data is sent as JSON you can deserialize by doing this:

```
protected async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token) {

    var bytesAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
    RemoteExecutionContext remoteExecutionContext = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RemoteExecutionContext>(bytesAsString);

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```

**Note:**

I had to install the nuget package `Microsoft.Xrm.SDK.2015` to get a reference to the `RemoteExecutionContext` class, this package is build using .Net Framework so is not properly compatible with .Net Core

Comment: Yeah. I ran into the same issue with respect to the classes in `Microsoft.Xrm.SDK.*`  only being for `.NET Framework`. Seems that MS has no plans to port them over. I _guess_ I could try to reproduce a **subset** of properties on the `RemoteExecutionContext` since ultimately all I need is the `id` of the entity that was created or modified...

Comment: Using the above it appears that when json.net tries to deserialize we get the following:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot create and populate list type Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KeyAttributeCollection. Path 'OwningExtension.KeyAttributes', line 1, position 7017.'

Answer (score 0):

The default serializer that the old service bus library uses is still available under an "Interop" namespace, although it only wants a Stream so you need to convert the byte array

```
protected async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token) {

    var deserializer = Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.InteropExtensions.DataContractBinarySerializer<RemoteExecutionContext>.Instance;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(message.Body))
    {
        RemoteExecutionContext remoteExecutionContext = deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as RemoteExecutionContext;
    }

    await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
}
```